# tilde-at-tilde character in vim

Tags: vim, text, unicode, encoding

I have just copy-pasted some text from a google doc into vim.

```
{
~@~\foo~@~]:{  
    ~@~\bar~@~]:{  
        ~@~\zoo~@~]:[~@~\* * * 0 0~@~]]    
    }
}
}
```

What is a ~@~ ? It appears to be hanging out where double quotes should be.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is I was using the "new" google docs, which has a feature called "smart-quotes" enabled by default.  This replaces your normal double-quote character with some special character code for opening quote, and a different one for closing quotes.  You can disable it in (Tools -> Preferences -> Smart Quotes)   https://support.google.com/docs/answer/57859?hl=en

Comment: So the problem seems to have been that you used an encoding that didn’t manage to display non-ASCII characters correctly.